# How to Print to Save as PDF from a command line with Chrome or Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, automation, chromium, print-to-pdf

Can I print to destination "Save as PDF" from a command line with Chrome or Chromium? I'd like to be able to automatically convert html files to PDF with Chrome's built-in functionality.

Comment: @golimar It is not a virtual printer. Chrome has a built-in option to export to pdf.

Comment: I don't see any built-in Chrome switches for saving as PDF.

Comment: @Karan When you go to `Print` there should be a `Save to PDF` destination available for you to choose. It's also clearly stated on Google's support page: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1379552

Comment: Perhaps my previous comment wasn't clear. You wanted to know how to do this from the command line, and what I wanted to say was that Chrome/Chromium seem to have no command-line switches/params to do this, although I know you can do it from the UI. You'll need to find some way of triggering the Save As option, perhaps by sending mouse clicks or key strokes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of calling up an entire web-browser, why not use the HTML rendering engine only to do the work? Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to perform the conversion.

[image: wktohtml]

You can also convert an existing website to PDF

```
$ wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

Note: technically Google Chrome's rendering engine is Blink, which is a fork of Webkit. There is >90% of common code between Blink and Webkit, so you should get a similar result.

Comment: Note from having tried this and getting subtle things missing or broken: wkhtmltopdf's source contains QtWebkit patches that enable important features such as clickable links. Your distribution's package is likely to be missing such features if it lists your distribution's usual qtwebkit package as a dependency. Installing wkhtmltopdf from source takes 3.7GiB of disk and some hours.

Comment: -1 This answer does not correspond to the question, wkhtmltox is a great tool but it does not perform as well as chrome or firefox on exporting to PDF.

Comment: @Anko Not sure I understood. What am I to expect by building wkhtmltopdf from source?

Comment: This isn't great for Javascript based websites. I've been trying it with https://stage-plan.com and it just doesn't work... Even raised bugs on github

Comment: can't recommend it either, if you have sophisticated CSS wkhtmltopdf is useless.

Comment: SVGs are not rendered.

Comment: -1 wkhtmltopdf is severely lacking for CSS3 documents

Comment: https://blog.rebased.pl/2018/07/12/wkhtmltopdf-considered-harmful.html

Comment: -1. I have hundreds of local HTML files that have Print stylesheets Chrome can handle. wkhtmltopdf takes almost 70 seconds per HTML file (unacceptable) and fails to render the page as it should with the proper Print stylesheet. This is an old answer, but even the updated version of this software is useless for this.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is garbage. Doesn't print emoji, forgot about supporting chinese fonts... yes you can try to get one or the another but... it doesn't work.

Answer (score 74):

Chrome has started [headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) program.

With that, we can create a pdf. e.g. for windows navigate your commandline to

```
C:\Users\{{your_username}}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application>
```

Then hit the command:

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="d:\\{{path and file name}}.pdf" https://google.com
```

Comment: Just a heads up, if you have any existing instance of Chrome running on Windows the command won't work. Kill all Chrome processes first, then it will work. There might be a flag to work around this inconvenience.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren (at least) as of Chrome for Windows Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit), this works without killing any Chrome processes.

Comment: Note that you can use `--user-data-dir="C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` to run under your user's Chrome profile.  This is useful, for example, for exporting content from a website that requires users to be logged in, since session cookies are available.

Comment: @naitsirhc FYI, I've found puppeteer to be a really good alternative to the command line stuff, if you trying to do something more elaborate. It has a nice API to remote chromium to do various tasks, it also manages versions for you. Very nice.

Comment: SVGs are rendered incorrectly

Answer (score 26):

You must be using Google Chrome / Chromium 59 or later version  <del>& it’s only available for MAC OS and Linux users.</del>

*** <del>Windows users still have to wait for some time till Version 60</del> ***

Command :

```
$ google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf http://www.example.com/

$ chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

Reference :
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

**EDIT :** Google Chrome / Chromium 60 has been rolled out for windows users.

Command usage in CMD :

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application> chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

Your pdf file naming **file1.pdf** will be save in

*"C:\Program Files or (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\60.0.3112.113 (chrome-version)\file1.pdf"*

Comment: `--disable-gpu` should not be necessary anymore in most recent versions.

Comment: this creates a MUCH better/consistent output than wkhtmltopdf or weasyprint

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf was designed exactly for this purpose.

The CLI looks like this: `$ electron-pdf http://fraserxu.me ~/Desktop/fraserxu.pdf`

Comment: I installed it, it hangs indefinitively without any output. I tried `electron-pdf http://fraserxu.me test.pdf` as suggested in the help, but I tried gooogle.com too

Comment: I opened issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17631#issue-427405049

Comment: See bugs https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20634 https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20634 - any app using Electron since version 6.1 (which you have to use to print untrusted HTML) will hang if page contains an `<iframe>` with cross-domain `src` attribute. The `electron-pdf` would be the correct choice if its quality were better.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little wrapper script for Chrome{,ium} headless, called [html2pdf](https://ucm.dev/t/bin.html/html2pdf).
Ghostscript is in there to reduce the file size, and to select a range of pages:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
in=$1 out=$2 page0=${3:-} page1=${4:-$page0}
${CHROME:-chromium} --headless --disable-gpu \
    --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf-no-header \
    --print-to-pdf="$out" "$in"
GS_ARGS=
if [ -n "$page0" ]; then
        GS_ARGS="-dFirstPage=$page0 -dLastPage=$page1"
fi
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH $GS_ARGS -sOutputFile="$2.tmp" "$2"
mv "$2.tmp" "$2"
```

Example usage:

```
html2pdf https://ucm.dev/resume.html ucm.pdf 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the `--print-to-pdf-no-header`, that's one parameter I still missed. Is there is list somewhere with the other parameters we know from the print dialog (like Margins, Scale, Paper size)?

Comment: From looking at [headless_shell_switches.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc) and [chrome_switches.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) it seems like those parameters aren't (yet?) mapped. For non-trivial scenraios [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) seems the way to go.

Comment: @mbx, the switches are indeed documented. First, for the original/classic chrome headless, they're at https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/#command-line-features. For the "new" engine (since 2021, accessed with `--headless=new`), they're at https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/#headless-specific-command-line-flags.

Answer (score 1):

Successfully did a batch conversion of local html files to PDF -- sharing the approach.

Navigate to a folder containing a batch of html files you want to convert...

```
for %f in (*.html) do (
start /wait chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:/[DESTINATION FOLDER PATH]%f.pdf" "C:/[SOURCE HTML FILE FOLDER PATH -- ALSO CURRENT FOLDER]%f"
)
```

Note -- must use forward slash to avoid negating the %f in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Can use this simple library from nuget package

For .Net Framework
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sats.HTMLtoPdf

For Core 3.1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sats.Core.HTMLToPdf

Usage#

```
var url = @"d:\convert.html";
var chromePath = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";

var output = new ChromeOptions().AddOptions(b =>
                    {
                        b.Headless();
                        b.DisableGPU();
                        b.WithoutHeader();

                    }).ToPdf(new ChromeDetails()
                    {
                        ChromePath = chromePath,
                        HtmlPath = url,
                        DeleteOutputFile = true, //optional
                       // OutputPath = @"d:\print.pdf" // (add if Environment.CurrentDirectory does not have access rights)
                    });


   File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\print.pdf", output.FileDetails.File);
```

For web application Set Process Model to LocalSystem

[image]