# Problems using chromium to print to PDF

Tags: pdf, chromium

I've been using the following solution on Linux:

```
chromium-browser --headless --print-to-pdf=example.pdf 'https://example.com/'
```

(which is the same as [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1229411/142948)) and it was working fine, but now it says:

> [0811/165809.082646:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(174)] Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled.

I'm on Chromium version `83.0.4103.97-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`.

I'm not trying to open multiple tabs, and the web pages I'm trying to get PDFs from don't open popup windows or anything like that.

Is this just a bug or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 as well, and I solved it by changing the executable to whatever is in Snap:

```
# uses /snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
$(find /snap/chromium/current/ -name chrome) --headless --print-to-pdf=example.pdf 'https://example.com'
```

I don't recall updating something, but this seems to work for me for now. Hopefully, it will work for you as well!